# Get String In <image> Tags With getValue of RSS Item - Android

Tags: java, android, rss

How can i get the string in `<image>` tags with getValue?`<image>https://i2.cnnturk.com/i/cnnturk/75/720x490/5e6f7a9a70380e0cc8f49313</image>`

i need `https://i2.cnnturk.com/i/cnnturk/75/720x490/5e6f7a9a70380e0cc8f49313` as value.

I'm able to show image, if it's `<media:content url=""/>` `<media:thumbnail url=""/>` `<enclosure url=""/>` and need to show `<image>` too.

Also is there  any way to format RSS publish date GMT to GMT+3? I need to show as different timezone.

RSS Item:

```
<item>
<guid isPermaLink="true">5e6f79fe70380e0cc8f49311</guid>
<link>https://www.cnnturk.com/turkiye/istanbul-barosundan-koronaviruse-karsi-avukatlara-acil-mesaj</link>
<title>
<![CDATA[ İstanbul Barosu&#39;ndan koronavirüs&#39;e karşı avukatlara &#39;acil&#39; mesaj ]]>
</title>
<description>
<![CDATA[ İstanbul Barosu Başkanlığı Koronavirüs nedeniyle &quot;Acil&quot; başlığıyla üye avukatlara mesaj attı. Mesajda duruşmaların 14 Nisan 2020 tarihinden sonra görüleceği, avukatlara bu süreçte dava açılmaması önerildi. ]]>
</description>
<pubDate>Mon, 16 Mar 2020 16:09:49 GMT</pubDate>
<atom:link href="https://www.cnnturk.com/turkiye/istanbul-barosundan-koronaviruse-karsi-avukatlara-acil-mesaj"/>
<image>https://i2.cnnturk.com/i/cnnturk/75/720x490/5e6f7a9a70380e0cc8f49313</image>
</item>
```

Here is android code:

Need help for

```
else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("image")) { //NEW ADDITION
            currentState = State.media;
                String attrValue = attributes.getValue("WHAT");
                item.setThumburl(attrValue);
```

_FULL CODE

```
@Override
    public void startElement(final String uri, final String localName, 
            final String qName, final Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {
        currentState = State.unknown;
        tagContent = new StringBuilder();
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item") || localName.equalsIgnoreCase("entry")) {
            itemFound = true;
            item = new RSSItem();
            currentState = State.unknown;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
            currentState = State.title;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("description") || qName.equalsIgnoreCase("content:encoded") || qName.equalsIgnoreCase("content")) {
            currentState = State.description;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("link") || qName.equalsIgnoreCase("origLink")) {
            currentState = State.link;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubdate") || qName.equalsIgnoreCase("published")) {
            currentState = State.pubdate;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("image")) { //NEW ADDITION
        currentState = State.media;
            String attrValue = attributes.getValue("WHAT");
            item.setThumburl(attrValue);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail")) {
            currentState = State.media;    
            String attrValue = attributes.getValue("url");
            item.setThumburl(attrValue);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("media:content")){
            currentState = State.media;   
            String attrValue = attributes.getValue("url");
            if (attributes.getValue("type") == null || attributes == null){
                return;
            } else if (attributes.getValue("type").startsWith("image")){
                item.setThumburl(attrValue);
            } else if (attributes.getValue("type").startsWith("video")){ 
                item.setVideourl(attrValue);
            } else if (attributes.getValue("type").startsWith("audio")){ 
                item.setAudiourl(attrValue);
            } 
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("enclosure")){
            currentState = State.media;   
            String attrValue = attributes.getValue("url");
            if (attributes == null || attributes.getValue("type") == null) {
                return;
            } else if (attributes.getValue("type").startsWith("image")){
                item.setThumburl(attrValue);
            } else if (attributes.getValue("type").startsWith("video")){ 
                item.setVideourl(attrValue);
            } else if (attributes.getValue("type").startsWith("audio")){ 
                item.setAudiourl(attrValue);
            } 
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String sete = "<image>https://x.com/a.jpg</image>";
String sete2 = sete.replace("<image>", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the regular expression `\<(\Qimage\E)\>(.*?)\<\/\1\>`To match the corresponding characters.It can match contents of all image labels.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s="<image>https://x.com/image.jpg</image>"
            + "<image>https://x.com/image1.jpg</image>"
            + "<image>https://x.com/image2.jpg</image>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\<(\\Qimage\\E)\\>(.*?)\\<\\/\\1\\>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()){
     System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
}
```

Update: I just updated the code. I'm sorry I wrote it wrong before.

if you don't want to use the regular expression

```
int record = 0;
while(record!=-1){
   int a = qName.indexOf("<image>",record);
   if(a==-1){
        break;
   }
   int b = qName.indexOf("</image>",a);
   String url=qName.substring(a+7,b+8);
   System.out.println(url);
```

}

Comment: this is not suitable. and it needs 2 more library. i just need inside of 1 tag from infinity rss recyclerview loop.
source: `<image>https://x.com/image.jpg</image>`
need: `https://x.com/image.jpg`

Comment: @tosunkaya I just updated the code. Please try again  :D

Comment: instead of these. when i used replace method, i got blank image. maybe i have to change `<`, `>`, `/` to unicode or something? I'm so close. qName is my full string.
`qName.replace("<image>", "");`

`qName.replace("</image>", "");`

Comment: @tosunkaya If you don't want to use regular expressions, you can use the indexof method. Position <image> and </ image>, then calculate the distance between them, and then use the String.substring (index, index) method to cut the string.

Comment: @tosunkaya I just updated the code that doesn't use regular expressions,  i wrote on my mobile phone, there may be errors in writing, please correct them.

Comment: your code works and the way i want in eclipse but in android studio, it makes my app crash. @VioletTec (previous code) i will try latest now

Comment: @tosunkaya I'm sorry I couldn't help you.

Comment: thanks for your time and help. the solution is String sete2 = sete.replace("<image>", "");